# Regular Expression to extract CSV data, some fields are quoted and contain commas

Tags: python, regex, csv, splunk

I have the following types of input data (for Splunk)

```
svr28pr,Linux File System-ALL,success,32.87,2638.259,26/06/14 19:00,26/06/14 21:03,avamar xxxxx1.network.local,Activity completed with exceptions.,26/06/14 19:00
SVr44PR:Staging_SyncDB,incr,success,1271,1271,27/06/14 11:28,27/06/14 11:28,SQL,,,1/01/70 09:59
```

I need to break this out into fields - the following expression worked well.

```
(?<client>[^,]+),(?<backuptype>[^,]+),(?<status>[^,]+),(?<size>[^,]+),(?<dump>[^,]+),(?<start>[^,]+),(?<complete>[^,]+),(?<application>[^,]+),(?<server>[^,]+),(?<comment>[^,]+)
```

However, due to a change in the names of the BackupTypes, the second field may be quoted and contain commas e.g.

```
svr08ts,"Windows VSS-ALL,ALL",success,0.067,39.627,26/06/14 21:32,26/06/14 21:38,avamar,xxxxxxx2.network.local,Activity completed with exceptions.,26/06/14 20:00
```

Is there a way using regex to determine whether a field uses quotes and if so to copy that data between quotes into a named group?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `multikv` in splunk to [process tabular data](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAFTU).

Answer (score 0):

As @thimoty-shields said, use the csv module

```
import csv
csvfile='backups.csv'
with open(csvfile) as csvfile:
    backups = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in backups:
        for cell in row:
            #do what you need
            print cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex to process your CSV files, use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module instead.  By default this will handle quoted fields. You can use `csv.DictReader` to produce a sequence of dictionaries akin to that returned by `groupdict()` on your re match object.

If your input file contains:

```
svr28pr,Linux File System-ALL,success,32.87,2638.259,26/06/14 19:00,26/06/14 21:03,avamar,xxxxx1.network.local,Activity completed with exceptions.,26/06/14 19:00
SVr44PR:Staging_SyncDB,incr,success,1271,1271,27/06/14 11:28,27/06/14 11:28,SQL,,,1/01/70 09:59
svr08ts,"Windows VSS-ALL,ALL",success,0.067,39.627,26/06/14 21:32,26/06/14 21:38,avamar,xxxxx1.network.local,Activity completed with exceptions.,26/06/14 20:00
```

This script

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

fields = 'client backuptype status size dump start complete application server comment'.split()
with open('input.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    reader.fieldnames = fields
    for row_dict in reader:
        pprint(row_dict)    # process the row here
```

would output:

```
{None: ['26/06/14 19:00'],
 'application': 'avamar',
 'backuptype': 'Linux File System-ALL',
 'client': 'svssi0000028pr',
 'comment': 'Activity completed with exceptions.',
 'complete': '26/06/14 21:03',
 'dump': '2638.259',
 'server': 'xxxxx1.network.local',
 'size': '32.87',
 'start': '26/06/14 19:00',
 'status': 'success'}
{None: ['1/01/70 09:59'],
 'application': 'SQL',
 'backuptype': 'incr',
 'client': 'SVr44PR:Staging_SyncDB',
 'comment': '',
 'complete': '27/06/14 11:28',
 'dump': '1271',
 'server': '',
 'size': '1271',
 'start': '27/06/14 11:28',
 'status': 'success'}
{None: ['26/06/14 20:00'],
 'application': 'avamar',
 'backuptype': 'Windows VSS-ALL,ALL',
 'client': 'svctx0000008ts',
 'comment': 'Activity completed with exceptions.',
 'complete': '26/06/14 21:38',
 'dump': '39.627',
 'server': 'xxxxxxx2.network.local',
 'size': '0.067',
 'start': '26/06/14 21:32',
 'status': 'success'}
```

and specifically,

```
>>> print row_dict['backuptype']
Windows VSS-ALL,ALL
```

as required.